# JQuery dialog only opens for the first record in the table

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I've seen many questions posted on this topic but none of the answers/suggestions seemed to work for me. I'm fairly new to JQuery so some assistance will be much appreciated!

I've got a table with links. For some reason I can only open the dialog box for the first record (I can do this multiple times). It doesn't work for any other records.

Here's my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 

         var dlg=$('#ticketDetails').dialog({
            title: 'Ticket Details',
            resizable: true,
            autoOpen:false,
            modal: true,
            hide: 'fade',
            width:850,
            height:700
         });


        $('#view').click(function(e) {

             //testing with static record
             dlg.load('displayRecord.php?id=215', function(){
                 dlg.dialog('open');
             });

          });

    });
```

all rows in the table has the following table link:

```
echo '<td><a href="#" id="view">View</a> </td>';
```

The div to display the dialog:

```
<div id="ticketDetails"> </div>
```

I also tried sticking `alert('1');` into the  `$('#view').click` function which does not fire for other records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your table, each row has the same id, "view". An id is supposed to be unique for a single element on a page, so you should change this to a class:

`<td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td>`

and change your script accordingly:

`$('.view').click(function(e) { ... });`

Inside the event handler, you can use the event variable `e` to get the element that was clicked, using its target property:

```
$('.view').click(function(e) {
  alert( $(e.target).text() );
});
```

Comment: I'm using pagination and it doesn't appear to work beyond the first page. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: When you set the click handler, it takes effect only for the `.view` elements that currently exist. If you load new elements, you need to make a call to the `click` method again. Could you post a link to the page, you are working on or make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi there, I'm using tablesorter pagination. If I view the source the entire table is loaded. When I goto the 2nd page and click on the view link it almost appears like its reloading the page instead of loading the dialog box. I even tried putting an `alert` inside the click event which doesn't appear to fire on page 2 onwards.

Comment: i found the problem. The tablesorter script was interfering with the load function. Fixed it by by moving the script after the load. Thanks for your help.